# reset main class

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

```
    package
    {
        public class Main extends Sprite {
        private var a=0;
        private var b=0;
        private var c=2;


        public function Main(){
            a=9;
            b=4;
            c=8;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there an easy way to reset all of my variables to the way they were when I first loaded the package so that I don't have to go through all of the variables and reset them manually?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no.  However, one solution might be to assign your class variables to new variables that you declare within your function.  That would preserve the initial values and makes them available to other functions.  A true "reset" would only happen if the class were re-instantiated.

Comment: I had a feeling that would be the answer, and I don't suppose there is a way to re-isnstantiate the Main() class, would there? assuming that the Main function was not immediately re-assigning the variables that is.

Comment: I don't believe so.  However, you could embed those values in a separate class and re-instantiate that class from within Main each time you need to reset them.  That creates some additional overhead, but would probably accomplish what you need.  +1 for the approach suggested by @Marty Wallace as that would retain your values without the overhead of a new class.

Answer (score 1):

You could **save** the variables when the class is initialised, and then load them back which would effectively be a reset. Try this:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class Main extends Sprite
    {
        private var _saved:Array = [];

        public var awesome:Boolean = true;
        public var val:String = "hello";

        public function Main()
        {
            saveVars("awesome","val","alpha");

            awesome = false;
            alpha = 0.5;
            val = "there";

            loadVars();

            trace(alpha); // 1
            trace(val) ;// hello
            trace(awesome); // true
        }

        /**
         * Saves defined vars
         * @param ...args A list of variables to save
         */
        public function saveVars(...args):void
        {
            _saved = [];

            var i:String;
            for each(i in args)
            {
                _saved[i] = this[i];
            }
        }

        /**
         * Loads from last save
         */
        public function loadVars():void
        {
            var i:String;
            for(i in _saved)
            {
                this[i] = _saved[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This has obviously the advantage of being able to save your variables at any point throughout the application runtime.

Answer (score 0):

late ?

Why not creating a new class loaded by the "Import" and "AddChild" syntaxes where you put your variables you remove and load again ?

Comment: Your suggestion is quite vauge and should be clarified by providing at least some pseudo-code of what you mean. Right now this answer isn't helping anyone.